# Flutter calling StatefulWidget's constructor caused expression can't be evaluated

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a stateful widget, and trying to call the superclass construction using `super(key: key`. However, I'm getting an error saying:

[image]

```
  class ArticlesPage extends StatefulWidget {
      ArticlesPage({Key key}) {
        super(key: key); 
      }
    
      @override
      _ArticlesPageState createState() => _ArticlesPageState();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For dart, `super` should be called in the initializer list. Ex:

```dart
ArticlesPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

If you also want to initialize fields here, you should do this before the `super` call. `super` should always be last in the initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save **key** from --> **Key key**  as a **class variable** also.

In this case, you will get a default GlobalKey value if it's not passed during constructor initialize.

```
AppStateFullWidget({Key key}):super(key: key ?? GlobalKey()){
    _key = super.key;
  }
```